# Lp spaces and sigma finite measure space

Tags: real-analysis

Not sure if my thought process is correct in the following question.

Q. Prove that there exists $f\notin L^1(X)$ such that for all  $1<p\leq \infty,  \ f \in L^p(X)$,  $\mu = $ Lebesuge measure

Note. $X = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_{k}$, where each $B_{k}$ are disjoint and $1 \leq \mu(B_{k}) \ < \infty $, $\mu(X)= \infty$

My Attempt:

Let $f = 1$ (constant) on all $B_{k}$, Then it is clear that the $L^1$ norm is infinite.

For $p>1$, $\parallel f\parallel_p = (\int_{X}^{} \mid f\mid^{p}  d\mu)^{1/p} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\int_{B_{k}}^{} \ \mid f\mid^p  d\mu)^{1/p} = (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_{k}))^{1/p}$

My intuition is that if I could take out the summation from the last expression by some inequality, then it would be clear that $f \in L^{p}$, but I'm not completely sure.

I also thought that rather than letting $f = 1$, I could let $f = 1/\mu(B_{k})$, and adjust the powers appropriately so that the summation above might converge. (Again, not sure if this approach is valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f=\sum_{n \geq 2} c_nI_{B_n}$ where $c_n =\frac 1 {n \mu(B_n)}$

Comment: For showing that $f \in L^{p}$ for $p>1$ remember that $\frac 1 {\mu(B_n)^{p-1}} \leq 1$ because $\mu (B_n) \geq 1$.

Comment: If instead we are given that $\mu(X) = \infty$ and $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, is it possible to always choose the $B_n$ so that $\mu(B_n) \geq 1$?